# How can I add new content to my Android app without present APIs?

Tags: android, rest, web-services

As a beginner I researched on it but couldn't find my answer on the web. For example I want to build an Android app which will contain some articles already. But when I want to add new articles to the app (without uploading new release of the app) how can I achieve this? I don't want to use present news APIs as said, I need to put my own content- what is your suggestions? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Use [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database). There you can deploy your mini-server. You can just remotely fill your database with news.

Example:  https://www.androidhive.info/2016/10/android-working-with-firebase-realtime-database/

Comment: oh thank you. Please pardon my ignorance but by mini-server do you mean adding new datas(articles) to Firebase database by using console manually? Because it may be an option too, I guess. Can you be more specific please?

Comment: Yes, you can add articles manually or use the API of some site, for example https://newsapi.org/